# In Chariot Race, do you incur a cornering penalty on being knocked back onto a numbered space after ramming?

Tags: chariot-race

We came across a curious situation in a game of Chariot Race where our reading of the rules seems to be curiously non-thematic. The situation was like this:

[image: red chariot one behind and to the right of the green chariot]

The red chariot is going to use its last movement to swerve and ram the green chariot. The rules on ramming say that when you ram someone as the final movement of your go, place the red chariot in the first unoccupied space behind the rammed chariot:

> If the ramming chariot ends its movement on a space
>   with a rammed chariot: the ramming is completed as
>   described above and the ramming chariot is placed on the
>   first unoccupied space in the same line behind the rammed
>   chariot. The rammed chariot stays in its space

However, the first unoccupied space behind the green chariot is a numbered corner space (3, obscured by the caltrop - sorry!). We were unsure about whether being bumped back onto that corner space would incur the penalty for cornering too fast. (The red chariot was travelling at a speed above 3.)

The rules on cornering say:

> Cornering at a wild gallop is not really a bright idea! High
>   speeds mean significant damage in corners. All numbered
>   corner spaces indicate the maximum safe speed when you enter
>   these spaces. Ending your movement in such a space counts
>   as entering the space. For each point of speed exceeding this
>   value you must take 1 point of damage. Adjust your Damage
>   Track accordingly.

My reading of this is that entering the space even when being placed back onto the space after ramming another chariot would incur the penalty. This doesn't seem to me to make much sense thematically, though - the penalty on cornering too fast would seem only to make sense when you're careering through a corner making forward progress, rather than when being bumped back one place after ramming someone.

Does anyone know if there's any official ruling on this, or how the rules on this should be interpreted?

(As a side note, we were also assuming that the red chariot would take damage from the caltrop on being bumped back into it, which *does* make sense thematically to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not take cornering damage when you're forced back into a corner space showing a maximum safe speed. You only need to do this when you enter the corner via normal movement.

Note, however, if there a string of chariots lined up around a corner and you had really bad dice, you might be forced to ram several of them in succession after taking cornering damage. You might then be forced back into an empty space *before* the corner such that on your *next* turn, you'd be forced to re-enter the corner again through normal means. In that case, you'd take damage from the corner again. I've never seen this happen, but it's theoretically possible.